# How to use computer to watch TV and to work on computer at same time

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I want to be able to use my desktop pc to do my work and surf the net, etc., using the computer monitor, and to send the signal to watch TV on the TV , at the same time.
so, what *components* are required to enable the computer to feed separate signals to both the monitor and the TV simultaneously?

Also, what *computer settings or preferences, etc.*, are required to enable the computer to feed separate signals to both the monitor and the tv simultaneously?
computer is **[HP Compaq Elite 8000](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-compaq-8000-elite-small-form-factor-pc/4065894/document/c01926347) w/Windows10 OS.**

I appreciate all relevant comments and feedback. please dumb it down, as I'm not technical.

Comment: All you need for most computers is a cable. If your computer has multiple outputs then you should be able to use at least 2 of them at once. As mentioned in the answer below we have no idea what variant you have and what graphics option you might have. You need to tell us what you have available.

Answer (score 1):

Does the computer have an HDMI socket on it*? if so you can connect to the TV & it will also carry sound. Any other connecter & you'd probably have to listen to your existing speakers, though you could output picture to the TV.

Any video output on the computer can be used to connect to the TV. The computer will consider it to be nothing more or less than a second display. All you need then is to play video to that display - usually settable from the player's prefs, eg in VLC…

[image]

*HP's site shows far too many graphics options on that model to even guess.
If you don't know, get a good clear picture of the rear panel on the computer.

Comment: Its also old enough that its either the onboard  *or* the discrete graphics option. Can't do both like some newer machines - like anything intel after sandy bridge